# Python Logging on Windows 8: IOError Errno 22

Tags: python, windows, logging

I have this very strange problem on a Windows 8 System: I log quite a lot of data to a `RotatingFileHandler` with the python standard logging library. The first few messages are no problem (~400 lines of log), after that I get the following error and the log is no longer written:

[image]

System and setup information:

- Windows 8 (could not replicate error on Windows 7)
- Python 2.7.6
- Log File Location: Path on network drive
- About 1 log entry per second
- About 3500 log entries in total (for 1 run of the script)
- logging configuration:

  ```
   LOGGING = {
      'version': 1,
      'disable_existing_loggers': False,
      'formatters': {
          'simple': {
              'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-25s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
              'datefmt': '%H:%M:%S',
          },
      },
      'handlers': {
          'log_file': {
              'level': 'DEBUG',
              'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
              'filename': 'meastool.log',
              'maxBytes': 1000000,  # ~ 1MB
              'backupCount': 2,
              'formatter': 'simple',
          },
      },
      'loggers': {
          '': {
              'handlers': ['log_file'],
              'propagate': True,
              'level': 'DEBUG',
          },
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Apparently you are not allowed to seek in the file. Even if you ask for seeking to the end of the file, as the OS sees this as past the end of the device. Perhaps you ran out of space?

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Space should not be a problem. If I run the same script from a Windows 7 PC and logging to the same file the error does not occur. Also I can restart the script on the Windows 8 Machine and the logging works again for the first few log entries. Or are you not talking about the network drive space?

Comment: Just trying to find possible causes. Can you create a test file in the same location with about the same amount of data and simply try to seek to the end? `fileobj.seek(0, 2)` means *seek 0 bytes relative to the end of the file*, and this is needed because the `fileobj.tell()` on Windows doesn't otherwise give the correct file size.

Comment: There is otherwise nothing special about the log rotating codebase here; it is just that the OS for some strange reason is telling you that the first parameter is an invalid offset. That or Windows 8 doesn't allow seeking from the end, period.

Comment: Is there any chance that another process is opening the logfile as it's being written?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: At the moment I have no access to the Windows 8 PC, so I can't check this one. But wouldn't this mean the error occours each time `emit()`is called?
@MarkR.: No, the file is not opened by other processes (At least not to my knowledge)

Comment: Hence the size part of my inquiries. Yes, that seek is called each time a message is emitted to the file.

Comment: I am reproducing this on Windows 10 as well, it doesn't appear to be specific to RotatingFileHandler, as I have also been able to reproduce with FileHandler.    The common issue is that it is a *path on network drive*.  I suspect that the stream is being closed do to some windows networking glitchiness.   I am investigating a solution that catches the exception and re-opens the stream.